# Will most Email readers support CSS to change all text font family?

Tags: css, html-email

I'm editing an email newsletter.

I'd like to change the default font. I'm hoping I can just change font for all text, without having to include a Style in a bunch of  or  tags.

perhaps one big DIV wrapper with font?

Answer (score 0):

Roughly 95% of email clients support CSS in the head so you can add it to the head with important tag. If there are fonts with important tag then this will not work.

Since you haven't provided any codes I would say if the above doesn't work you can try to do a find and replace. It works most of the time.